# Resharper warnings window

Tags: resharper, resharper-4.5

I'm using ReSharper for my solution (that contains 10 projects) and I'd like to see the hints/suggestions/warnings/errors (listed in a window) for a chosen project. How can I do that?

**Note**: the solution analyzer window shows **only** errors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Doesn't seem to be an available option with the current release of Resharper...

> We are not going to include warnings
> in SWA in ReSharper 4 release cycle.
> This is due to complexity of some of
> analyses, due to complexity of UI to
> deal with thousands of possible
> warnings, and so on and so forth. We
> are going to improve SWA in many ways,
> we have a lot of plans, but they need
> some time to implement. I can't say
> any specific dates right now, but I
> think we can add more solution-wide
> features in the next major release
> after ReSharper
> 4.0.
>
> As a workaround, you can set severity of warnings you are
> interested in to the "error" level.
> You may have to restart VS to force
> SWA reanalyse files.

Source:
http://www.jetbrains.net/devnet/thread/273096

Comment: Wait, how can I even view the warnings then?

Comment: @marczellm after the addon installed there appears a menu «Resharper». Go to *«ReSharper»→«Inspect»→«Code issues in solution(or Project)».*

Answer (score 10):

In ReSharper 5, you can right-click solution explorer and select Inspect Code. It will show you all the issues found in the selected scope. There is a button on the toolbar to filter issues.